# Can I rely on def do ... after ... end syntax?

Tags: elixir

It seems that a function definition can have an `after` clause just like the `try` statement:

```
# after.exs
defmodule M do
  def f do
    IO.puts "hello"
    raise "die"
    IO.puts "world"
  after
    IO.puts "bye"
  end
end

iex(1)> M.f
hello
bye
** (RuntimeError) die
    after.exs:3: M.f/0
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
```

Though this is not documented in [Kernel.def/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#def/2), [Kernel.SpecialForms.try/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html), or [Getting started - Named functions](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/modules.html#named-functions).

Is this a supported feature? Can I rely on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This only seems to be documented in [this place](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/try-catch-and-rescue.html). I'm not sure if you understood its purpose, but as that page says, it is a shortcut for ommitting the try line:

> Sometimes you may want to wrap the entire body of a function in a try construct, often to guarantee some code will be executed afterwards. In such cases, Elixir allows you to omit the try line:

```
iex> defmodule RunAfter do
...>   def without_even_trying do
...>     raise "oops"
...>   after
...>     IO.puts "cleaning up!"
...>   end
...> end
iex> RunAfter.without_even_trying
cleaning up!
** (RuntimeError) oops
```

I've personally never used it and don't recall ever seeing it in any code besides the above example. I also could not find anything about it in the docs besides in the docs about try [try documentation](https://devdocs.io/elixir/elixir/kernel.specialforms#try/1). The only way I usually use the `after` word is with `receive do`:

```
iex> receive do
...>   {:hello, msg}  -> msg
...> after
...>   1_000 -> "nothing after 1s"
...> end
"nothing after 1s"
```

I believe this is a mapping from Erlang, so you may want to ask this to someone knowlegdeable in Erlang. However, I found this particular mail in the Erlang mailing list interesting:

[Joe Armstrong about try-catch-after](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2014-November/081894.html)